# Как сгруппировать строки по первому столбцу и самой длинной строке второго столбца в SQL?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Есть таблица с двумя столбцами:

1. authorID
2. BookName

Нужно создать запрос, в котором после его выполнения в первом столбце не будет повторяться authorID, а во втором столбце будет самое длинное название BookName этого автора.

Например, в следующей таблице

```
authorID          BookName
   4              Финансист
   4              Титан
   4              Стоик
   7              Эгоистичный ген
   7              Слепой часовщик
   9              Код да Винчи
   9              Инферно
```

чтобы после запроса осталось так:

```
authorID          BookName
   4              Финансист
   7              Эгоистичный ген
   9              Код да Винчи
```

И, скорее всего, не каждый обратил внимание, что у authorID = 7 оба названия книг имеют одинаковое кол-во знаков. Так вот, чтобы брало первую по списку.

Comment: что такое первую по списку - с минимальным id? как ваш вывод отсортирован?

Comment: И укажите какой же sql вы используете. Даже просто получение длины строки в mysql и mssql делаются разными функциями. А собственно выбор из нужных длин делается кардинально разными способами (еще сильно зависит от версии сервера)

Comment: @Mike использую SQL Server Management Studio 2012

Comment: @splash58 нет, не с минимальным id, по сути, можно любую из нескольких, если одинаковое кол-во знаков, т.к. строки одинаковые

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct authorID, 
  (select top 1 with ties BookName from books t1 where t1.authorID = t2.authorID order by 1 desc)
  from books t2;
```

Comment: работает, но выбирает не самую длинную строку со столбца BookName

Comment: я заменил "order by 1" на "order by len(BookName)" и стало как мне надо, спасибо)

Comment: Ну, да, естественно.

Answer (score 0):

Короче говоря, это самый идеальный запрос:

```
select distinct authorID, 
    (select top 1 BookName 
    from books t1 
    where t1.authorID = t2.authorID
    order by BookName asc) BookName 
from books t2
where authorID is not null
order by authorID
```

Answer (score 0):

Для поиска строки с максимальным значением и вывода всех данных этой строки можно использовать `Top N with ties` с оконной функцией в `order by`.
Вот пример запроса:

```
SELECT top 1 with ties authorID, bookname
from books
order by row_number() over (partition by authorID order by len(bookname) desc)
```

Еще один из вариантов - использование оператора `cross apply`

```
SELECT b.authorID, bb.bookname
from books b
cross apply (select top 1 bookname from books bbb
where b.authorID=bbb.authorID
order by len (bbb.bookname) desc) bb
group by b.authorID, bb.bookname
```

Тут можно посмотреть [фиддл](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=eee9e6e36698d958f7379ada514072e0)